# conversion of text file to html file by extracting tables from text file and generating the html file using python

Tags: python-3.x

We have text file and from that text file we need to extract the table. Table looks like this. Keeping in mind that the numbers of columns is varying.

```
+--------+---------+-------+
|        |         |       |
|  Name  |   Addr  |  city |
+--------+---------+-------+
```

We need to generate the html file where this table is shown in a proper table view.

I have done this for the static columns but for the dynamic columns I am facing problem.

Comment: What is your problem? Describe and show what you tried and any results you get. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the syntax of your table there. But I think you can use

```
String.split('|')
```

to extract the columns in your table. Or use regex's if it's more complicate than that....